# How to assign app delegate reference to a view controller property in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, xcode

Declared in MyViewController.h:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

In viewDidLoad of MyViewController.m:

```
self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
localAppDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

For some reason appDelegate remains null, but localAppDelegate is properly assigned.

Why doesn't self.appDelegate get properly assigned?

Comment: whats the point of defining an instance of the app delegate as property ?!

Comment: I am working through trying to get different view controllers to share information.  I am trying to do this by storing the data as an object in the app delegate, then accessing it using the code above.  When I access it within viewDidLoad, localAppDelegate works fine, but when I try to do the same within a method for a custom nav bar button, localAppDelegate doesn't work... so I am wanting to store the pointer to the app delegate in viewDidLoad.  I am new to ObjC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well Erik based on your comment localAppDelegate should be always accessible but be sure to import AppDelegate header to the class you want to use appDelegate inside it .. and if you need to store a variable's like user settings , common variables ..etc. I prefer to use `NSUserDefaults` its simple and recommended to use in cases like this .. here is a simple example to save and get string from `NSUserDefaults`

1. To set :

   `NSString *str = @"Malek";

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:str forKey:@"myName"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

2.to get :

```
NSString *myName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myName"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems much simpler... I'll try that.

Comment: @Erik if my answer helped you please marked it as accepted answer by clicking at the tick beside the answer.